# I want to make a command using discord.py which triggers when someone react to the message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def qna(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('what is the color of mango\na. red\nb. blue')
    await msg.add_reaction("️")
    await msg.add_reaction("️")]
```

Here's what I did till now 
Please someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Bot.wait_for`

```py
async def qna(ctx):
    reactions = ["️", "️"]
    msg = await ctx.send('what is the color of mango\na. red\nb. blue')
    for r in reactions:
        await msg.add_reaction(r)

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and reaction.message == msg and str(reaction) in reactions

    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
    # Do something with the reactions
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)